# Make a clean install file for OSX

Tags: macos, install

I have a Mac mini with OS X El Capitan 10.11.x installed.

I want to change to a new hard disk and reinstall the OS and data. I don't have the installation file for OS X El Capitan, as I bought the computer with it installed.

Is it possible to make an installation disk using which I can perform a clean installation of OS X El Capitan.

I need to run OS X El Capitan 10.11, as some critical software I use runs only on this release.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12 might work still

Comment: That's only available if the Mac is not capable of running anything newer. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: @Tetsujin Eh. That can be bypassed.

Comment: If so, it might make a nice addition to the linked QA. It's not something I've ever tested as I have all the installers right back to Lion right here ;)

Comment: @JBis how can you bypass it ?

Comment: Come to chat → https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80948/how-to-bypass-the-app-store-el-capitan-restrictions